# Sql query not running

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I run the following query on phpmyadmin then it gives me following error

```
INSERT INTO `infrastructure_support_info`(`s_no`, `student_no`, `books_availability`, `basic_requirements`, `technological_support`, `study_material`, `resource_availability`, `cleaniliness_of_class`)
VALUES ('', '', '$availabilityOfBooks', '$basicRequirements', '$technologicalSupport', '$photocopyOfStudyMaterial', '$availabilityOfOtherResources', '$cleanlinessOfClass')
```

> #1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`feedback_system_db`.`infrastructure_support_info`, CONSTRAINT `user_std_no` FOREIGN KEY (`student_no`) REFERENCES `user_master` (`student_no`))

Answer (score 2):

Your table has a reference to another one. If you want to leave that link empty then use `null` instead of a blank string `''`.